# How to define pressing Ctrl twice as a keyboard shortcut in Linux (to launch a command)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to launch a command by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> twice? 
Is there any AHK-like program available in Linux which can do this?

Comment: Most key combination used for shortcuts require that a modifier key (such as `Ctrl`) are pressed together with an _actual_ key that it modifies. A program could certainly catch `Ctrl` pressed once, but I haven't seen any programs that allows for double key shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using X11 (and not Wayland), there are many tools to "spy" on the keyboard events. One example is [cnee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cnee). If run with

```
cnee --record --keyboard
```

when you press a key, such as <kbd>Control_Right</kbd>, you will get output such as

```
6,2,0,0,0,105,0,299533174,3,Virtual core keyboard
```

which has fields giving details about the event including if up or down (2), the keycode (105 in my case), and the time of the event in milliseconds (299533174).  A simple script can look for two successive down events for the same keycode that occur in, say, less than 500 milliseconds, and run some command. For example,

```
cnee --record --keyboard 2>/dev/null |
awk -F, -v wanted=105 '$1==7{
 down = ($2==2); keycode = $6; tod = $8;
 if(keycode==wanted){
   if(down){
     diff = tod-last
     if(diff>500){ last = tod; next } # note time of first press
     else{
       #printf "%s %s %d\n",down?"down":"up",keycode,diff
       system("echo hello")
     }
   }else next
 }
 last = 0
}'
```

Note, you will need to change the `wanted=105` value to the appropriate keycode, and the `$1==7` to match your keyboard's index.